# C# PageMethods javascript callback function is not being called

Tags: javascript, c#

I have java script function in an aspx page as shown below which calls below line

`PageMethods.PopulateData(x, y, z, onSucceeded_PopulateData, onFailed_PopulateData)`

The onSucceeded_PopulateData() call back java script function is not being fired if the page remained idle for more than 1 minute.

Can anybody provide solution for this?